# Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit even though maxContentLength is set to infinity

Tags: typescript, axios

I need to send a big amount of data with Axios, however, I am getting the following error

```
Error: Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit
```

For this, I am trying to modify the Axios config with the following interceptor

```
 axios.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
  console.log('intercepting');
  config.maxContentLength = Infinity

return config;
```

});

This is not modifying the body limit and hence the error persists.

I have read that `config.maxBodyLength = Infinity` could be used for this but when trying to use it, I get the following typing error:

```
Property 'maxBodyLength' does not exist on type 'AxiosRequestConfig'.
```

How can I config axios to allow a bigger payload?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
declare module 'axios' {
    export interface AxiosRequestConfig {
        maxBodyLength?: any;
    }
  }
```